# PHP 4 to 5 changes to php.ini

Tags: php

I noticed my PHP .ini file is the one from PHP4 even though I am running PHP 5 now.

When changing session.cookie_httponly and session.cookie_secure I noticed they weren't there so am wondering if there are other declarations that might be missing.

I'm especially wondering about security but is there anything else that is important?

Comment: Bearing in mind PHP5 came out nearly 10 years ago, you might be hard pressed to find many people who would remember this sort of thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Differences

You can find all old `php.ini` recommendations online, for example the one from PHP 4.4 [on Github](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-4.4/php.ini-recommended).

You also can find the new recommendations online, for example the one for PHP 5.3 [on Github](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-5.3/php.ini-production).

You can diff those with any tool (for example [this site](http://www.quickdiff.com/) provides an online differ), which should give you a good overview on what changed in the last years.

## What I would do

Please notice that actually all PHP distributions contain the `php.ini-recommended` or `php.ini-production`. You can just pick this file and fit it to your needs, which should result in a much better configuration file than you updating your old file manually.

Comment: Thanks, it turned out there wasn't really many differences but worth doing I should think.